# SQL convert\cast nvarchar to int

Tags: sql

I have a lot of '1.0' values of type nvarchar(max). I would like to convert\cast them to int but below queries:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(int, Quantity)
  FROM MyTable
```

or

```
 SELECT CAST(Quantity as int)
  FROM MyTable
```

or

```
 ALTER TABLE MyTable
  ALTER COLUMN [Quantity] int;
```

returns error message:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1.0' to data type int.

How to convert nvarchar '1.0' to int?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Judging by your nonanglophone name, I'm guessing your SQL Server is configured to use the European radix (a comma) instead of the English/American radix (a dot), hence the error.

Comment: 1.0 is not really an integer. It is a decimal value with the precision of one decimal place. So I guess you need two steps: 1. convert the string into a decimal, 2. convert the decimal to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to an appropriate format first:

```
update mytable
    set quantity = convert(decimal, quantity)
    where quantity like '%.%';
```

Then do the `alter table`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43f2c7ff7702b0b4aeec9de50dc32726) is a db<>fiddle using SQL Server.